# What are the contents of a gitlab backup tar file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I accidentally deleted the .tar file created by gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create

I need to re-create the .tar file manually from the folders and files under the folder /var/opt/gitlab/backups

I want to know what all goes into the tar file. Is it everything in the above folder?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out. It is ALL the contents of the /var/opt/gitlab/backups folder.

I tarred them all into a new tarball and then restored gitlab from the new tarball. All seems to work fine.